# jQuery selector : get the content of 1st element class containing specific word

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

Quick jQuery selector question :

I need to get the content of the first element (`div`/`span`/...) having a `class` containing a string (eg : "price").

Something not like this ;o) :

```
var price = ( $('[class*=price]').text() );
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine using the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$('[class*="price"]:first').text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Et3vx/1

Comment: @user1045587 you said not like `class*=price`

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think he meant `$('[class*=price]').text()` doesn't work. Which it doesn't because it is missing the `:first` selector

Comment: @RichardD he should be much clearer...I dont have to guess things

Comment: @user1045587 : Sorry for my english/explanation. RoyiNamir is right, I meant this expression does not work...

Answer (score 1):

`$('[class*=price]:eq(0)').text()` would give you the required o/p.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$('[class*="price"]').eq(0).text()
```

Demo - http://jsbin.com/ogonap/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Quotes are mandatory in the attribute contains value selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":contains('price')").text();
```

I'd imagine that should work. Haven't managed to test it.

Documentation for :contains is here http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#text
Basically finds the element containing your string and returns the class.

EDIT: My bad, I thought you meant search for the string 'price' and return all text.